# How best to store an arbitrarily complex data structure in a relational DB?

Tags: sql, database-design, orm

It seems like this must be a solved problem, but I can't find an appropriate pattern/guide.

I'm trying to move our settings from a config file to a database.  An API will be acting as gatekeeper, so worst-case, I could just dump json blobs into the database and rely on the API to manage everything.

That approach feels dirty and has the added downside that should I ever need to update a setting from within SQL, I'm either writing convoluted queries to parse Jsopn or doing it by hand.

So, I'd like the be able to store the settings in the database using appropriate data types and with a normalised schema.

As I'll need to store settings used by multiple services, I can't make any assumptions about the structure and complexity - think XML config file.

I don't need to understand the context, but I do need to be able to persist/retrieve the structure flawlessly (and possibly output multiple formats (json/xml/yml/etc))

As an example of what I may need to persist:

```
{
  "Servers": ["a", "b", "c"],
  "Port": 1234,
  "RetryOnFail": true,
  "Plugins": [
    {
      "Name": "Plugin1",
      "Filters": {
        "a": [51, 42, 22],
        "b": ["chomp", false, 12]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd ideally like to be able to handle the case where subsequent children aren't guaranteed to match the same structure, eg `{"children": {"a": 1}, {"b": false}, [12, 11]}` but if that's a bridge too far, I can live without it.

I have no strong preference whether the actual values are stored in one wide table (field per data type) or a series of tiny tables (one per data type), but in either case, I'll need a table or two that describe the structure of the settings.

So... What's the correct way to store this schema in the database? I'm aware I'll need to track data types, and the like. If this were a simple tree, I'd point each setting at its parent. I can still do that, but it seems like I'm going to need additional information for context - IsDictionary, IsList, etc...

I can't see an elegant, normalised way to do this (shy of actually generating tables for each element on-the-fly but that seems very over-engineered for such a simple problem and comes with either security concerns or multi-database complexity).

This is the route I started down, but it feels like a dead-end

```
class settings(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "settings"
    Component = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    IsSensitive = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    IsLocked = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    Key = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Type = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    Root = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='Descendents')
    Parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, related_name='Children')


class settings_date(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "settings_date"
    Setting = models.ForeignKey(settings, null=False, related_name='AsDate')
    Key = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    Value = models.DateTimeField(null=False)

# etc...
```

Comment: Suppose I have a config file here and you tell me how to map it to a description of the state it represents, and I'll make a relational design. Your mapping is going to involve a bunch of descriptive statement templates whose named blanks get filled in by file fragments. All I'll do is have a table per template with a column per name. You can do that yourself! Your post seems to be a straightforward exercise in relational design--as usual, where you know the problem and we don't. Please just give *some* design (templates/tables) *with justification* & ask for obvious deficiencies.

Comment: Well, If you are going to store documents, perhaps a document-db is a better choice than a relational db. We've recently been working with MongoDB for storing documents, and it seems to be a better approach than attempting to match a relational schema for each possible document.